# Prove that {$b_n$} is convergent with $ b_n \to L$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\lbrace a_n\rbrace$ be a convergent sequence with $a_n \to L$

Define $$ b_n = \frac{ a_1 + a_2 + ... a_n}{n}  \forall n \in \mathbb Z_+ $$

Prove that $\lbrace b_n\rbrace$ is convergent with $ b_n \to L$

I tried to go through $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} f \{a_n \} = f \lim_ {n \to \infty} \{ a_n \} $  but I can't figure out $f$.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216657/convergence-problem) is the first duplicate I found.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565288/can-you-please-check-my-cesaro-means-proof) is another (with additional links contained in its "linked" section).

Answer (score 0):

Recall the definition of convergence: $\forall \epsilon \exists N$ such that $\forall n > N$, $|a_n-L| < \epsilon$.

As a hint, try it with $L=0$.

Another hint: for a given $\epsilon$, you want the average of the first $k$ $a_n$s, but you can use as many $|a_n-L|<\frac \epsilon 2$ as you need to get the average low!